# Track changes in word document using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openxml, docx

I have two document version1.docx and version2.docx which have some text inserted or deleted from either of the document. My task was to able to find the inserted and deleted text, which I was able to do that. The output generated was the third document result.docx with the marked css styles for inserted and deleted text.

So, the result.docx will have the inserted text marked with underline and deleted text marked with strike. Now, I want to use the concept of track changes in result.docx which will give the user a choice to accept or reject the changes. So, user should have option to accept/delete the inserted/deleted part in the result.docx. I have used the [openxml-docx](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/openxml-docx/0.10.6) ruby gem for creating and writing text in result.docx but I could not find any track change properties in it.

is there any other ruby gem for docx which have the option of track changes ?. It is possible in VB or C#.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are asking. Are you saying "given two docx files, I'd like to show the difference"? Or, "Given one docx file with tracking changes enabled, I'd like to display that data"? Or, has this question actually got nothing to do with docx files per se - and all you really want to do is display the difference between two plain text files? (Also, why is this tagged as `ruby-on-rails`? It's got nothing to do with rails.)

Comment: I was able to find the difference b/w two docx files which I have displayed in  the third docx file. Now, I want to give user a choice to either accept the inserted/deleted text shown in third document  for which I will be required the property of track changes in docx. I want to do it using some ruby gem. Let me know if you have any other approach.

Comment: @vegeta were you able to solve this? I'm particularly looking to merge two files and have differences marked as "tracked changes" in the docx